# subversion validation

Tags: svn, svn-hooks

We use subversion as a source control solution; however couple of my team mates aren't very faithful when it comes to provide a comment while checking in files.

I would like to put a couple of validation like...

A. A comment is mandatory with at least a specified number of characters.
B. Few words must be present in the checking in comment.
C. spaces in file names are rejected.

Is there a way to do so? I tried searching for a solution but it seems that isn't going that well...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can employ a [**pre-commit hook**](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch05s02.html) to check if a comment comes with the commit and which files are altered or added.

A pre-commit hook script obtains the repository that's to be changed and a *transaction* identifier. Both these can be used with [`svnlook`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch09s03.html):

```
svnlook log /path/to/repo --transaction <txid>
```

This will echo the commit message.